# Javascript wont show in Firefox geoip_city()

Tags: javascript, geolocation, location

I use this code;

```
<script language="text/javascript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
<script>

   var city = geoip_city();
   document.write (city)

</script>
```

This works on Google Chrome but not working for Firefox, how to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `language` attribute.

It is required in HTML 3.2 (and supported in HTML 4.x Transitional) but isn't needed now. If it does exist, then the value needs to be `JavaScript`, not `text/javascript`.

The value `text/javascript` is appropriate for the `type` attribute. This was introduced (and made mandatory) in HTML 4.x. It was made optional in HTML 5, so you don't need it at all.

```
<script src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still not working on firefox i have now;

<code><script src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
<script>
   
    var city = geoip_city();
    document.write (city)

</script>

Comment: It works for me (aside from MaxMind not knowing what city I'm in so returning an empty string in their JS)

Comment: Huh is it working for you with Firefox? Strange why it should work on me with Chrome and not with Firefox ^o)

Answer (score -1):

The `geoip.js` file path has been changed, please follow the correct URL `//js.maxmind.com/js/geoip.js` and it is working for me.